# multiple divs inside a class:

Tags: html, css

I have this html:

```
<div class="container">

    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul><a href="welcome.php">Create Offer</a></ul>
        <ul><a href="pending.php">Accept Offer</a></ul>
        <ul><a href="pending.php">Pending</a></ul>
        <ul><a href="pending.php">Completed</a></ul>
        <ul><a href="pending.php">Balance</a></ul>
        <ul><a href="pending.php">Support</a></ul>
    </div>

        <div id="items">
            Text
        </div>

</div>
```

this is the css:

```
.container { 
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: white;
border: 1px  solid black; 
width: 1000px; 
}

#sidebar {
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
width: 18%;
background-color: #E3E3E3;
height: 100%;
}

.container #items {

width: 82%;
float: right;
background-color: red;
}
```

output: http://puu.sh/l719c/52f182e1d2.png

why wont the items div show within the container  in the white space next to the sidebar?

thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have just missed one line. The float for the sidebar must be set so that other elements can use the empty space. Change your css for #sidebar as follows.

```
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 18%;
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @whoever_did_the_down_vote why down vote..?? any problems...??

Answer (score 1):

When you float an element, it moves to the side and lets content that follows it move up beside it.

That means the content that **follows** `items` (if there was any) would be next to it.

You've done nothing to let `items` move up beside `sidebar`.

You need to float `sidebar` left and not `items` right.

Also beware of horizontal margins/padding making the total width of the elements add up to more than 100%.

Also note that floated elements do not restrict the height of their container unless you [do something about it](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59).

I'd generally look to [flexbox](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/) for aligning blocks on a row, rather than floats.

Comment: Flexbox still has [pretty poor support across browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) (good ol' IE)

Comment: how can i move items up beside sidebar?

Comment: i did that, but the div is stuck to the bottom http://puu.sh/l72pU/98e3280959.png i removed the float: right and added a margin-left so it skips the sidebar area.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you want your sidebar set to float:left;. So you can position the "items" right next to the "sidebar" div.